# Selenium unable to click() on "btn3d"

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

I'm using Selenium in Python to download a file as a bot. However, I am facing problems clicking in a button... When I click the "Búsqueda Avanzada" (advanced search) button manually to deploy a bar for a query, it goes ok, but through Selenium a white page appears. I guess the my problem is that I'm trying to click a 3D button which can't be done in a simple way as other buttons.

The simplified HTML code from the webpage would be:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="Toolbar">
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td nowrap="" class="TBGroup TBGroup2">
            <a class="advancedsearch btn btn3d tbbtn" href="javascript:" style="position:static" arwindowid="3">
               <div id="TBadvancedsearch">Búsqueda avanzada</div>
            </a>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

The summarized script I've been trying to go with, is the following:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    
    
    action1 = ActionChains(driver)
    
    element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#Toolbar > table > tbody > tr > td.TBGroup.TBGroup2 > a.advancedsearch.btn.btn3d.tbbtn')
    action1.move_to_element(element)

    btn_adv_search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'TBadvancedsearch')))
    action1.move_to_element(btn_adv_search)
    action1.click()
    action1.perform()
```

But what should be the deployment of a query bar, turns out to pop a TimeoutException or refresh as a kind of a blank page?

Comment: After you mouseover on <a> tag, observe the dom carefully, may be one more <a> tag might show up automatically in the dom inside <div> tag with id 'TBadvancedsearch'

Comment: Nothing shows, only thing that happens is that  "btn3d" changes to "btn3ddown" when I click

Comment: Try to click or locate button using [xpath](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html#locating-by-xpath)

Comment: That's what I was trying, but at the end I coulded solve it by using  Katalon (code generator for web scrapping) and the XPath it showed (and worked) was:   


 

 "(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Mis informes'])[4]/following::div[1]"